# laravel - blade templates layout structure add row-fluid for each 4 spans

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have this blade template

```
<div class="row-fluid">
 @foreach($courses as $course) 
 <div class="span3 learn">
   Content
 </div>
 @endforeach
```

Output

```
  <div class="row-fluid">

   <div class="span3 learn">
     Content
    </div>
   <div class="span3 learn">
     Content
   </div>
   <div class="span3 learn">
     Content
   </div>
   <div class="span3 learn">
     Content
  </div>

   <!-- this span should be in a spearted row-fluid div -->
  <div class="span3 learn">
     Content
  </div>

</div>
```

this code adds a block of span3 size I use Twitter bootstrap reponsive
I need to add row-fluid for each 4 spans in the row-fluid div

I want the output to be like this

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3 learn"> Content </div>
    <div class="span3 learn"> Content </div>
    <div class="span3 learn"> Content </div>
    <div class="span3 learb"> Content </div>
 </div>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3 learn"> Content </div>
    <div class="span3 learn"> Content </div>
    <div class="span3 learn"> Content </div>
    <div class="span3 learn"> Content </div>
 </div>
```

I don't know how to achieve this in laravel @foreach

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could use `array_chunk` on `$courses->all()` to split it in groups of 4, and make a nested @foreach. Something like this:

```
@foreach (array_chunk($courses->all(), 4) as $courseRow)
    <div class="row-fluid">
        @foreach ($courseRow as $course)
            <div class="span3 learn">...</div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Awesome thank you, just edit all to all() because it's a function thank you again

Comment: Thank you very much. You really made my work a lot easier this evening. Keep on the good work.