# Laravel 5.4 Nested Loop with Grouped dataset

Tags: php, laravel, loops, nested

"Filters" table looks like following:

```
id |  group   |       label       |        value        
----+----------+-------------------+----------------

 12 | deadline | 1 to 3 days       | 1 AND 3            
 14 | price    | Any               | 0                  
 15 | price    | Less than 1000    | 0 AND 1000         
 16 | price    | 1000 to 10000     | 1000 AND 10000     
 22 | location | Any               | 0                  
 23 | location | New York          | newyork            
 24 | location | California        | california         
 25 | location | Alabama           | alabama
```

I need to show chunk of "label" under the "group".

My controller:

```
public function index(){
        $filters = Filters::all();
        return view('frontend.request', compact('filters'));
    }
```

My view has:

```
<?php foreach ($filters as $filter) { ?>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <b>{{ $filter->group }}</b>
                        <div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="{{ $filter->group }}" value="{{ $filter->any }}">{{ $filter->label }}</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
```

I want to show all labels under the group within one box and so on. The above codes create different boxes for each label which is not right.

I believe, its got to be nested loop but I'm having difficult writing it on Laravel. Any idea how it should be?

Note: This thread gives partial answer but we don't know chunk size in my case: [Laravel 5.1 - Nested Loop - Blade Templating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418743/laravel-5-1-nested-loop-blade-templating)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Laravel's `groupBy()` collection method;

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-groupby

Controller:

```
public function index(){
    $filters = Filters::all();
    $groups = $filters->groupBy('group');
    return view('frontend.request', compact('groups'));
}
```

View:

```
@foreach ($groups as $group => $filters)
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <b>{{ $group }}</b>
        @foreach($filters as $filter)
            <div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="{{ $filter->group }}" value="{{ $filter->any }}">{{ $filter->label }}</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforech
```